# Using jOOQ in Quarkus - SQLDialect needs to be defined manually

Tags: quarkus, jooq

When using jOOQ together with the Quarkus Framework, i need to pick the SQL-Dialect manually, because it is not picked-up / resolved from the typical `application.conf` setting. For example: `quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mariadb` for mariadb.

I can resolve it manually, by defining an additional property in the `application.conf` and resolve it manually.

See following example:

```java
...
final Optional<@NotNull SQLDialect> maybeSqlDialect =
        Arrays.stream(SQLDialect.families()).filter(x -> x.name().equalsIgnoreCase(jooqDialect)).findFirst();
if (maybeSqlDialect.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("sql-dialect not found! " + jooqDialect);
}
final SQLDialect sqlDialect = maybeSqlDialect.get();

Configuration configuration = new DefaultConfiguration()
        .set(dataSource)
        .set(sqlDialect)
        .set(new Settings()
          ...
        );
...
```

is it possible to let jOOQ automatically resolve the SQLDialect from the `javax.sql.Datasource`, or are there other alternative i may not know of, to make jOOQ correctly select the SQLDialect for my quarkus datasource configuration, that i setup in the application.conf file?

Used Versions:

- Quarkus 3.8.2
- jOOQ 3.19.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ itself won't resolve the `SQLDialect` from the `javax.sql.DataSource` alone, because to do so, it would have to call `DataSource.getConnection()`, which is potentially a costly operation. The `SQLDialect` is already necessary before the `Connection` is fetched, and not all interactions with jOOQ will require a `Connection`. E.g. when logging formatted SQL, the generated SQL requires only a `SQLDialect`, not a `Connection`, as it isn't executed.

If you can provide jOOQ with a JDBC `Connection` instead, then it can find the `SQLDialect` from the meta data, however:

```java
// This dialect is inferred:
DSL.using(connection).configuration().dialect();
```

Alternatively, if you know how your `DataSource` is set up (e.g. from a properties file), then you can also use [`JDBCUtils.dialect(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/tools/jdbc/JDBCUtils.html#dialect(java.lang.String)) to have jOOQ look at the JDBC URL to derive the `SQLDialect` family at least. The dialect version can't be detected this way either, for that, a JDBC `Connection` is also necessary (and its `DatabaseMetaData` API)